# Как правильно написать слово "ненайденный"?

Tags: грамматика

В контексте: *получатель, ненайденный в списке.*

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***получатель, не найденный в списке.*** Поскольку есть зависимые слова *(не найденный где? в списке),* пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно писать раздельно. Во-первых, по чисто формальной причине: есть зависимое слово. Во-вторых, думаю, что слова "ненайденный" просто нет в словарях. И в-третьих, отрицание же явно чувствуется.

Comment: Орфографический словарь-справочник: **ненайденный.** https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/51152/ненайденный