# Можно ли существование причастия с приставкой "не" проверить по словарю (орфографическому, толковому)?

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные, причастия

Этот вопрос по теме другого вопроса (я пока не могу спросить отвечающих в комментариях): [Как правильно написать слово "ненайденный"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452614/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Причастия "ненайденный" нет в толковом словаре Кузнецова, а в орфографическом словаре есть только слово "найденный", но, может быть, оно просто в этих словарях не указывается. Можно ли в этом случае сказать, что слово  "ненайденный" не существует вообще?

Можно ли причастие "ненайденный"  без зависимых слов  назвать прилагательным? Другими словами, может ли оно перейти в прилагательное? Вот в таком предложении все слова являются причастиями?

Ненаписанные книги, незавершенные замыслы, НЕНАЙДЕННЫЕ параллели, неприведенные цитаты так и не дождутся своего автора.

Comment: Здесь ссылаются сразу на три словаря: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/92230/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно, приставка "не" сединяется с большинством причастий.

Comment: В таком контексте – вопросов нет. Вероятно, я там был не прав. Спутал причастия с прилагательными. Например, в парах неширокий – неузкий, невысокий – ненизкий и т.п. вторых слов просто не существует (почему-то). И с этим надо считаться.

Comment: Да, Вы правы, слово "неузкий" не встречается в текстах, и в словаре его нет, в отличие от слова "неширокий". Я думаю, что оно просто лишнее. Этот ряд  выглядит так: широкий - средний (не широкий и не узкий) - неширокий (довольно узкий) - узкий.  Этих слов, вероятно, достаточно, чтобы обозначить все варианты.

Comment: А вот с "большим" все в порядке: большой – немалый – средний – небольшой – маленький.

Comment: Да, верно. Но почему-то  "немалый" вместо "немаленький".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Буду отвечать иерархично:

1. На мой взгляд,  нет никакой необходимости указывать в толковом словаре слова, имеющие отрицательный характер и не обладающие каким-либо отдельным значением. С тем же успехом можно каждое слово в русском языке занести в словарь.
2. А теперь минутка "просвещения". Тема сходности причастий и прилагательных довольно трудна, однако между этими частями речи всё же есть существенные отличия в значении. Отглагольное прилагательное и причастие, хотя и совпадают по форме в **отдельных случаях**, имеют совершенно разные значения, характеризующие предмет по отличным друг от друга признакам. Также есть различия и в написании. Сравним:

"Войска собра**н**ы командиром".

"Войска собра**нн**ы и вежливы".

В первом случае смысл в том, что войска **были собраны командиром**, то есть он их **собрал**. При таком условии это слово является кратким **причастием**. Во втором же случае войска имеют такие качества, как **собранность** и вежливость. Здесь слово является кратким **отглагольным прилагательным** и необходимо для **описания** не действия, а самого объекта. В обоих случаях я рассматривал **краткие** формы, чтобы было, на мой взгляд, понятнее. То же самое можно сказать и о полных формах, от которых образованы данные слова.

В нашей ситуации слово "ненайденный", как и его неотрицательная форма, может являться только причастием,  ибо нет такой характеристики объекта, как "найденность".

Во всех перечисленных Вами случаях слова следует рассматривать как причастия.

Comment: Да, спасибо, Вы правы, если нового значения нет, а только отрицание, то не имеет смысла указывать его в толковом словаре. И качественное значение у слова "ненайденный" как-то не находится. Мне просто показалась неясной информация, данная в ответах.

Comment: В отличие "найденности", _ненайденность_ широко эксплуатируется литераторами и публицистами как синоним _потерянности_ или _невостребованности_. Поиском по книгам можно найти многие десятки таких примеров.

Comment: Но всё же согласитесь, что даже при таком значении переход в прилагательное с сохранением значения весьма сомнителен.