# "Не( )найденные дороги" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не, слитно-раздельно

***"Не( )найденные дороги"*** - как пишется: слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Предложите, пожалуйста,  свой вариант ответа.

Comment: И где ударение у второго слова: дорОги или дорогИ?

Answer (score 4):

*Испепеленные души! **Ненайденные дороги!** Испитое до дна отчаянье...* (А. Ветлугин. Авантюристы гражданской войны)

"**Ненайденные** сокровища" (книга. Б. Бродского)
"**Ненайденные** ромашки" (книга Э. Арутюняна)
"**Ненайденные** сокровища Эстонии" (название конкурса)
Несохранившиеся и **ненайденные** письма, июнь 1897 — декабрь 1898 (А. П. Чехов. ПСС)

> **2.** Пишутся слитно с частицей ***не*** прилагательные, которые в сочетании с этой частицей приобретают противоположное значение (обычно такое слово можно заменить синонимом без *не*): ***не**большой* (ср. *маленький*), ***не**женатый* (ср. *холостой*), ***не**настоящий* (ср. *ложный, притворный*).

Синонимы к "ненайденный" — потерянный, утраченный.

Вне контекста рассуждаем так: прилагательное полное, синоним имеется, противопоставления нет, пояснительные слова *далеко, вовсе, отнюдь* или отрицательные местоимения и наречия (начинающиеся с *ни*) отсутствуют.
Делаем вывод: пишем слитно.

Для сравнения: никем не найденные книги; не найденные деньги, а заработанные.

[§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=74#pp74)

Comment: А другие зависимые слова: еще не найденные книги.

Comment: В морфологическом словаре онлайн(а это, насколько мне известно, словарь Зализняка) найденный — причастие.

Comment: При разборах в Сети найденный –  причастие, а ненайденный —  прилагательное.

Comment: @Sharon, ну не может частица изменить часть речи.

Comment: @Серж Это же не мое мнение, а мнение большинства. Я привела его для справок.

Comment: Большинства лингвистов?

Answer (score 2):

Причастие при отсутствии зависимых слов пишется слитно с частицей "не": ***ненайденные дороги*** -  это дороги, которые не нашли.
***ЭТО НИ В  КОЕМ СЛУЧАЕ НЕ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ!***

Comment: А вы уверены? Все (при морфологическом разборе) пишут, что прилагательное. Я задавала такой вопрос  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452619/Можно-ли-существование-причастия-с-приставкой-не-проверить-по-словарю-орфогра   Мне тоже непонятно, где здесь качественное значение. Но большинство, как всегда, правы))

Comment: Абсолютно. В заданиях ЕГЭ полно таких примеров. Не может тут быть никакого качественного значения, тем более что даже нет подходящего синонима-прилагательного, да и слова такого в МАС даже не представлено.

Comment: Я вот сейчас просмотрела несколько разборов  в Сети, и у всех это прилагательное. Стала думать, в чем дело. А какой способ образования, приставочный? Но тогда слово мотивируется причастием, а не глаголом. Может, в этом дело? А словарь... Таких форм много, все не запишешь. Приставка НЕ практически со всеми  причастиями соединяется. Но здравый смысл говорит, что это причастие таки.

Comment: Мне кажется, что сначала причастие должно перейти в прилагательное при переносном значении, и тогда из него можно получить прилагательное с приставкой НЕ.

Comment: @Sharon Явно не от всех причастий образуются прилагательные посредством "не". Например, данного слова я ни в одном словаре не нашел, а значит оно не может быть прилагательным априори. К слову, другие прилагательные, образованные с помощью "не", там фиксируются. Зачем же такое исключение было сделано для данного слова? Наверно потому, что оно является обычным причастием.  Еще один момент: какое у данного слова тогда стативное значение, если оно является прилагательным?

Comment: Еще один важный вопрос. Если у нас с помощью "не" образуются только прилагательные, то куда подевались все причастия, употребленные без зависимых слов, Почему в одном случае причастие может употребляться самостоятельно (без зависимых слов), а как только появляется "не", то такой способности оно лишается, не бред ли?

Comment: Убедительно... Я решила задать отдельный вопрос по теме.

Comment: @Ajgy Слово "ненайденный" имеется в словаре-справочнике Б. З. Букчиной и Л. П. Какалуцкой. (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/51152/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) Синоним: потерянный.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Это орфографический словарь? Нет. Авторские словари никакого веса не имеют. С каких пор для якобы прилагательного подбираем синоним-причастие?

Comment: Э-э... Это Букчина и Какалуцкая никакого веса не имеют? Слитно или раздельно? Орфографический словарь-справочник.  http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/together-or-separately/index-205.htm#ab%D0%9D%D0%95

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Может, еще на словарь Даля будем ориентироваться или к Срезневскому обратимся? Вот единственный авторитет в области грамматики после Грамматики-80: https://orfo.ruslang.ru/search Где вы там нашли это слово?