# Ненайденный (и все подобные слова) — причастие или прилагательное?

Tags: прилагательные, причастия, терминология

Это [дополнение к теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474775/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)

**1. Вопрос уже обсуждался на форуме [в 2019  году](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452619/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)**

Тогда был приведен такой  «убедительный»  довод: все считают, что это **прилагательное.**  Ну что ж, все так все, **приходится так считать**. Но для себя я назову это явление так: **непроявленный** признак по действию в прилагательном.

**2. Почему есть желание считать слово причастием**

Такого прилагательного нет в словаре.

Нет качественного признака.

Нет синонимов среди качественных прилагательных.

Нет признаков адъективации  причастия (перехода в прилагательные). Признаки перечислены [в теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474335/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

При появлении зависимых слов и раздельном написании НЕ (еще не найденные книги)  «прилагательное» становится  « причастием»?

**3. Почему это слово считают прилагательным (предположение)**

Потому что договорились так считать.

Есть проблемы с**о словообразованием** слова  «ненайденный». Если это приставочный способ, то может ли слово образоваться от причастия, а не от глагола? Это вряд ли возможно... Поэтому приходится считать, что "ненайденный" образуется **от прилагательного "найденный".**

**4. В чем же истинная причина принятого решения (предположение)**

Мы считаем причастия и деепричастия **формами глагола,** но они выглядят достаточно самостоятельными. Может, пора предоставить им автономию? Тогда можно будет образовать причастие «ненайденный» от причастия «найденный».

Или надо найти **еще какое-то решение**. Другой вариант — привести убедительный **довод** в пользу прилагательного. А иначе здравый смысл пользователей будет постоянно вступать **в противоречие** с логикой формального анализа.

**5. Вот пользователи и [фантазируют](https://prochastirechi.ru/chast-rechi/nenaydennye)** на эту тему

Это неосновная часть речи? Ну тогда ее нужно считать частицей. Как вам нравится такой "вывод"?)) А еще считают, что обе формы образовались **[от глагола](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3024220-kak-pishetsja-nenajdennyj-ili-ne-najdennyj.html)**,
но как? И все это результат **неопределенности** в различении причастий и прилагательных.

**И конкретный вопрос:** Какой частью речи вы считаете слово «ненайденный» и почему (перечень ваших **доводов**)?

Comment: Sharon, я посмотрел в морфологическом словаре, о котором я говорил в предыдущем ответе, там "ненайденный", действительно, прилагательное. Других официальных источников мне найти не удалось.

Comment: Серж, я в этом не сомневалась, о словарях мне сказал еще Alex_ander в 2019 году.  Так надо считать, но почему так надо считать?  Давайте вы в поле ответа назовете свои личные доводы в пользу прилагательного (как вы сами думаете), а  я добавлю еще информации по этой теме. Не хотелось бы, чтобы все пропало в чате.

Comment: Sharon, да, когда я искал информацию, я наткнулся на этот ответ. Тогда я его не видел, а может и видел, но забыл. Но там мне не удалось ничего найти.